# How to pass parameters to a subroutine acting on an extern file in batch

Tags: batch-file, parameters, subroutine

If I write

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%a in (1,1,%NUMBER%) do (
    ECHO #define BLE_UUID_!SERVICE_NAME_UC!_!CARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[%%a]!_CHAR   !CARACTERISTIC_UUID[%%a]!
)
```

Where *NUMBER*, *SERVICE_NAME_UC*, *CARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[%%a]* and *CARACTERISTIC_UUID[%%a]* have been set before, everything works fine and I obtain:

```
#define BLE_UUID_SECURITY_RELAY_CMD_CHAR        0x4800
#define BLE_UUID_SECURITY_RELAY_STATUS_CHAR     0x4801
#define BLE_UUID_SECURITY_CONFIG_CHAR   0x4802
```

But, what I'd like to do is to call a subroutine inside the FOR loop that does the task, such as in this way:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%a in (1,1,%NUMBER%) do (
    CALL :SetOutput_h %INPUT_HEADER_PATH%\DefCharUUID.txt %%a
)

GOTO:EOF
:SetOutput_h
:: Subroutine to insert parts of code in the  header output file
:: The argument for this subroutine is the NAME of the code part you want to insert in the output file
SET "PART_NAME_H=%~1"
SET "INDEX=%~2"
(FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('findstr /N "^" %PART_NAME_H%') DO (

   REM Get the line *including* !variable! replacements
   SET "line=%%A"

   REM Remove leading number, show the rest *including* empty lines
   ECHO(!line:*:=!

)) >> %OUTPUT_H%
GOTO:EOF
```

Where the file *DefCharUUID.txt* just contains this:

```
#define BLE_UUID_!SERVICE_NAME_UC!_!CARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[%INDEX%]!_CHAR    !CARACTERISTIC_UUID[%INDEX%]!
```

The output file genarated contains this:

```
#define BLE_UUID_SECURITY__CHAR
```

So, parts with square brackets have been ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you `CALL`ing `:SetOutput_h` with two arguments, the first of which is completely superfluous to that for loop? If you just `SET "PART_NAME_H=%INPUT_HEADER_PATH%\DefCharUUID.txt"` prior to that loop you would only `CALL :SetOutput_h %%a` and `SET "INDEX=%1"` Although I also note you don't appear to be using `%INDEX%` either!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the line:

```
SET "line=%%A"
```

The loop variable `A` has the string value:

```
#define BLE_UUID_!SERVICE_NAME_UC!_!CARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[%INDEX%]!_CHAR    !CARACTERISTIC_UUID[%INDEX%]!
```

Delayed expansion is applied on assigning this string to environment variable `line`.

But immediate expansion for `%INDEX%` is not done anymore. Windows command interpreter expanded all environment variable references using `%VariableName%` already on parsing entire **FOR** command block beginning in your code with `(FOR /F` and ending with `))` before command **FOR** is the first time executed at all.

For that reason `!SERVICE_NAME_UC!` is replaced by string `SECURITY` on assigning the line read from file to environment variable `line`. But Windows command interpreter fails to find an environment variable with name `CARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[%INDEX%]` and another environment variable with name `CARACTERISTIC_UUID[%INDEX%]` resulting in both environment variable pseudo array references being replaced by an empty string.

I'm not sure why you coded the header file creation such complicated, but here is the solution for your problem which contains extra lines for a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) not leaving any file behind after batch file execution finished.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "NUMBER=3"
set "SERVICE_NAME_UC=SECURITY"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[1]=RELAY_CMD"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[2]=RELAY_STATUS"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[3]=CONFIG"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_UUID[1]=0x4800"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_UUID[2]=0x4801"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_UUID[3]=0x4802"
set "INPUT_HEADER_PATH=%TEMP%"
set "OUTPUT_H=%TEMP%\output.h"
del "%OUTPUT_H%" 2>nul
echo #define BLE_UUID_!SERVICE_NAME_UC!_!CHARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[%%INDEX%%]!_CHAR    !CHARACTERISTIC_UUID[%%INDEX%%]!>"%INPUT_HEADER_PATH%\DefCharUUID.txt"

for /L %%I in (1,1,%NUMBER%) do (
    call :SetOutput_h "%INPUT_HEADER_PATH%\DefCharUUID.txt" %%I
)

type "%OUTPUT_H%"
del "%OUTPUT_H%"
del "%INPUT_HEADER_PATH%\DefCharUUID.txt"
endlocal
goto :EOF

:SetOutput_h
:: Subroutine to insert parts of code in the header output file.
:: The argument for this subroutine is the NAME of the code part you want to insert in the output file.
set "INDEX=%~2"
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N "^" "%~1"') do call :ExpandLine "%%L"
goto :EOF

:ExpandLine
set "Line=%~1"
call set "Line=%Line%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Line=%Line%"
echo(!Line:*:=!>>"%OUTPUT_H%"
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

The provided solution passes the line read from file to one more subroutine. The passed line is first assigned to environment variable `Line` in the subroutine `ExpandLine`.

Next environment variables using immediate expansion are expanded using the command line:

```
call set "Line=%Line%"
```

After this command line the environment variable `Line` has on first run of main **FOR** loop the string value:

```
#define BLE_UUID_!SERVICE_NAME_UC!_!CHARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[1]!_CHAR    !CHARACTERISTIC_UUID[1]!
```

Now delayed expansion is enabled and this line is expanded once more using additionally delayed expansion before printing the two times expanded line to the output file.

I'm quite sure that what you really want to achieve could be done much easier as demonstrated below which omits `[%INDEX%]` in file `DefCharUUID.txt` completely:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "NUMBER=3"
set "SERVICE_NAME_UC=SECURITY"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[1]=RELAY_CMD"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[2]=RELAY_STATUS"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[3]=CONFIG"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_UUID[1]=0x4800"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_UUID[2]=0x4801"
set "CHARACTERISTIC_UUID[3]=0x4802"
set "INPUT_HEADER_PATH=%TEMP%"
set "OUTPUT_H=%TEMP%\output.h"
del "%OUTPUT_H%" 2>nul
echo #define BLE_UUID_!SERVICE_NAME_UC!_!CHARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC!_CHAR    !CHARACTERISTIC_UUID!>"%INPUT_HEADER_PATH%\DefCharUUID.txt"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%I in (1,1,%NUMBER%) do (
    set "CHARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC=!CHARACTERISTIC_NAME_UC[%%I]!"
    set "CHARACTERISTIC_UUID=!CHARACTERISTIC_UUID[%%I]!"
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N "^" "%INPUT_HEADER_PATH%\DefCharUUID.txt"') do (
        set "Line=%%L"
        echo(!Line:*:=!>>"%OUTPUT_H%"
    )
)
endlocal

type "%OUTPUT_H%"
del "%OUTPUT_H%"
del "%INPUT_HEADER_PATH%\DefCharUUID.txt"
endlocal
```

Some more hints:

**GOTO** is the command and `:EOF` is the parameter. Don't write them together although Windows command interpreter handles also `GOTO:EOF` after applying an error correction.

It is advisable to reference other scripts or applications like **FINDSTR** with full path and file extension in a batch file to make the batch file independent on current values of the local environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH` as much as possible.

Enclose all file/directory references in double quotes even if not really needed with current file/directory names/paths because who really knows the file/directory names/paths in future.